# Clourethan Product in USA

Tags: usa

Does anyone know if there is a product in the USA or Canada that is similar to the European Clourethan Product? Also, if there is such a product what is the name and a source for purchasing it? I appreciate any recommendations.

Thank you

Comment: A link would help

Answer (score 2):

In the US, the generic name for a comparable product is polyurethane and one widely-known brand is [Minwax](http://www.minwax.com/wood-products/clear-protective-finishes/interior/minwax-fastdrying-polyurethane). Polyurethane can be found in home improvements centers (Home Depot, Lowe's), dedicated painting supply stores (Sherwin Williams, PPG, Glidden), hardware stores (Ace), and in home improvement sections of stores such as Walmart and Target.